# Creating title page in latex

Tags: titles

I need to create a title page of the given format

```
                           **(Title of the Thesis)**

                                  Thesis

            Submited in partial fulfilment of the requirements of

                           BITS C421T/42T Thesis

                                    By

                                  (Author)

                                  ID No. ( )

                         Under the supervision of

                          ---------------------- 
                    (Name and Designation of Supervisor)

                              Instiute emblem

        BIRLA INSTITUTE OF TECHNOLOGY AND SCIENCE, PILANI (RAJASTHAN)

                                  (Date)
```

I am new to latex, and am miserably failing to do so. I tried the center the lines by using the command \center, but even that is not working. How should I go about creating said titlepage? Also, how do I embed an image in the title page?

Comment: Don't worry we've all been there.  But if you are unfamiliar even with `\begin{center} <text goes here> \end{center}`, you might want to read the venerable [The Not So Short Introduction to LaTeX2e](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/lshort), which has been translated into many different languages.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You should pretty easily be able to search this site for questions and answers about how to insert images. Have you thought about using a dedicated class/package/template for writing a thesis? See, for example, [LaTeX Templates by ShareLaTeX](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/) or [LaTeX Templates](http://www.latextemplates.com/).

Comment: @AdamLiter- I know this is probably not in the spirit of this site, but I need to submit this report today, and I just cannot create the title page. Could you please help me with the code for this? It's perfectly alright should you choose not to.

Comment: If you are really only stuck on the titlepage, how did you produce an entire thesis in LaTeX while now being new to it? If you really have a thesis to submit today and you really are new to LaTeX, now is not the time to learn it. Use whatever you've been using. Submit. If you want to learn LaTeX, do it afterwards. This is just not something which you can pick up and format something of this kind on that kind of time scale.

Comment: @cfr- I used a template on sharelatex. However, the titlepage is not in the desired format.

Answer (score 1):

There are much better ways to do this, but if time is of the essence and you don't really care about most details...

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\parskip=14pt%
\vspace*{3\parskip}%
**(Title of the Thesis)**

Thesis

Submited in partial fulfilment of the requirements of

BITS C421T/42T Thesis

By

(Author)

ID No. ( )

Under the supervision of

\rule{7cm}{0.4pt}\\
(Name and Designation of Supervisor)

Instiute emblem

BIRLA INSTITUTE OF TECHNOLOGY AND SCIENCE, PILANI (RAJASTHAN)

(Date)
\end{center}
\newpage

Rest of file.

\end{document}
```